# Quicksort implementation: nearly sorted when using random pivot

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, quicksort

I'm working on implementing quicksort as a bit of practice and review for myself. Currently this is just a simple implementation for a primative integer array. After getting this working fine, I plan on making it generic.

What I have below still has a slight bug in it that I haven't been able to track down. I originally wrote it to simply use the left index as the pivot, and everything worked fine. However, once I finished writing it and switched it to use a random pivot, things aren't quite right anymore. My test arrays become nearly sorted, but a few elements are still two or three indices away from where they should be.

Here are a few of my test cases that demonstrate incorrect behavior when run through this:

`6, 5, 1, 3, 8, 4, 7, 9, 2`

`1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

`5, 4, 3, 2, 1`

```
 /**
 * Sort an integer array using quicksort
 * 
 * @param a Array to sort
 */
public static void quicksort(int[] a) {
    partition(0, a.length - 1, a);
}

/**
 * Partition a section of an integer array around a randomly selected pivot within that section
 *
 * @param left Lower-bound index of section (inclusive)
 * @param right Upper-bound index of section (inclusive)
 * @param a Array to perform partitioning within
 */
private static void partition(int left, int right, int[] a) {
    // Exit if partition is only a single element
    if (right - left < 1) { return; }

    // Select a pivot at random
    int pivot = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(left, right + 1);

    // Move pivot to left-most position (get out of the way)
    swap(left, pivot, a);

    // Perform partitioning
    int cur = left + 1;
    for (int i = left + 1; i <= right; i++) {
        if (a[i] < a[pivot]) {
            swap(i, cur, a);
            cur++;
        }
    }

    // Put pivot back where it belongs
    swap(left, cur - 1, a);

    // Partition the two new partitions
    partition(left, cur - 2, a);
    partition(cur, right, a);
}

/**
 * Swaps two elements in an array of integers
 *
 * @param i Index of first element to swap
 * @param j Index of second element to swap
 * @param a Integer array to perform swap on
 */
private static void swap(int i, int j, int[] a) {
    int temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
}
```

Comment: could it be ThreadLocalRandom things seem fine when I run with new java.util.Random(right+1 - left) + left? I ran the code at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php.

Comment: Never mind . I see it.

Comment: You're swapping the pivot element with the element on the far left, but you haven't updated the index of the pivot when you're comparing elements against it in the partitioning step. I'm not sure if that's the culprit, but it's certainly something you might want to look into.

Comment: @templatetypedef Gah, that was it!  I can't believe I missed that...  Such a stupid mistake. Thanks!  You should post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer:

In this part of the code, you're swapping the pivot element with the leftmost element:

```
// Select a pivot at random
int pivot = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(left, right + 1);

// Move pivot to left-most position (get out of the way)
swap(left, pivot, a);
```

However, you haven't actually changed the index of the pivot element. That means that in this partition logic, you're looking at the wrong index in the array:

```
for (int i = left + 1; i <= right; i++) {
    if (a[i] < a[pivot]) {
        swap(i, cur, a);
        cur++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  A simple `pivot = left;` after the initial swap is all that was missing!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try using left instead of pivot. It will reverse the sort of the list.

```
if (a[i] > a[left]) {
            swap(i, cur, a);
            cur++;
}
```

You did not account for the change.

I am more used to working with the pivot to the right. I kept your implementation small. My issue was, first right must be > left and quicksort of partition (left,cur-1,a) is likely necessary.

The swapped position should already be sorted as well. You account for this though in the right based method it would be.

```
partition(left, cur -1 , a);
partition(cur + 1, right, a);
```

You can read up on the implementation at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

My code runs at coding ground.

```
public class HelloWorld{

   int[] a = null;



    /**
 * Sort an integer array using quicksort
 * 
 * @param a Array to sort
 */
public void quicksort() {
    partition(0, a.length - 1, a);
}

/**
 * Partition a section of an integer array around a randomly selected pivot within that section
 *
 * @param left Lower-bound index of section (inclusive)
 * @param right Upper-bound index of section (inclusive)
 * @param a Array to perform partitioning within
 */
private  void partition(int left, int right, int[] a) {
    // Exit if partition is only a single element
    if (right <= left || right - left == 0) { return; }

    // Select a pivot at random
    int pivot =  left + new java.util.Random().nextInt(right - left);
    pivot = right;

    // Move pivot to left-most position (get out of the way)
    swap(right, pivot, a);

    // Perform partitioning
    int cur = left;
    for (int i = left; i < right; i++) {
        if (a[i] <= a[right]) {
            swap(i, cur, a);
            cur++;
        }
    }

    // Put pivot back where it belongs
    swap(cur, right , a);

    // Partition the two new partitions
    partition(left, cur -1 , a);
    partition(cur + 1, right, a);
}

/**
 * Swaps two elements in an array of integers
 *
 * @param i Index of first element to swap
 * @param j Index of second element to swap
 * @param a Integer array to perform swap on
 */
private void swap(int i, int j, int[] a) {
    int temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
}


     public static void main(String []args){
         int[] arr = new int[]{0,4,2,3,9,11,20,100,50,32,45,27,13,2,1,4,99,1,4};
         HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();
         hw.a = arr;
         hw.quicksort();
         for(int i = 0;i< arr.length;i++){
             System.out.println(arr[i]);
         }
     }
}
```

Here is the code with pivot to the left.

```
public class HelloWorld{

   int[] a = null;



    /**
 * Sort an integer array using quicksort
 * 
 * @param a Array to sort
 */
public void quicksort() {
    partition(0, a.length - 1, a);
}

/**
 * Partition a section of an integer array around a randomly selected pivot within that section
 *
 * @param left Lower-bound index of section (inclusive)
 * @param right Upper-bound index of section (inclusive)
 * @param a Array to perform partitioning within
 */
private  void partition(int left, int right, int[] a) {
    // Exit if partition is only a single element
    if (right <= left || right - left == 0) { return; }

    // Select a pivot at random
    int pivot =  left + new java.util.Random().nextInt(right - left);


    // Move pivot to left-most position (get out of the way)
    swap(left, pivot, a);

    // Perform partitioning
    int cur = left + 1;
    for (int i = left +1 ; i <=  right; i++) {
        if (a[i] < a[left]) {
            swap(i, cur, a);
            cur++;
        }
    }


    // Put pivot back where it belongs
    swap(cur - 1 , left , a);

    // Partition the two new partitions
    partition(left, cur - 2 , a);
    partition(cur , right, a);
}

/**
 * Swaps two elements in an array of integers
 *
 * @param i Index of first element to swap
 * @param j Index of second element to swap
 * @param a Integer array to perform swap on
 */
private void swap(int i, int j, int[] a) {
    int temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
}


     public static void main(String []args){
         int[] arr = new int[]{6, 5, 1, 3, 8, 4, 7, 9, 2};
         HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();
         hw.a = arr;
         hw.quicksort();
         for(int i = 0;i< arr.length;i++){
             System.out.println(arr[i]);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution does work, but it turns out the only thing wrong with the existing code was that I forgot to update the index of the pivot after swapping it to the left.

Comment: Just going from memory from class.